# How to update multiple items in an array with usestate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having some trouble with the React `useState` hook. I have a list of recipe ingredients already stored in state/array called `modalIngredients`

That array looks like this when I log it:

```
[
    {
        "raw": "1 (4-5) pound chuck roast",
        "name": null,
        "quantity": 1,
        "unit": ""
    },
    {
        "raw": "salt + pepper",
        "name": null,
        "quantity": 0,
        "unit": ""
    },
    {
        "raw": "2 tablespoons olive oil",
        "name": null,
        "quantity": 2,
        "unit": "tablespoon"
    }
]
```

I am trying to update the `name`, `quantity` and `unit` for each item in the array/state by calling a function called (`parseIngredient`) that parses the raw field and spits out a result that looks like this for each ingredient in the array

```
{
   quantity: 300,
   quantityText: '300',
   minQuantity: 300,
   maxQuantity: 300,
   unit: 'gram',
   unitText: 'g',
   ingredient: 'flour'
}
```

Where I have been able to get so far is to map the modalIngredients array and log the `ingredient`, `unit`, `quantity` output from the `parseIngredient` function and log these out to the console.  This works and returns the data I am hoping to use to update in the `modalIngredients` array.

Here is what this code looks like:

```
{modalIngredients.map((modalIngredient) => {
    const parsedIngredient = parseIngredient(modalIngredient.raw, 'en')
    return (
        console.log(parsedIngredient.ingredient),
        console.log(parsedIngredient.unit),
        console.log(parsedIngredient.quantity)
    )
})}
```

So this is where I start to struggle as I have never had to update all the items in an existing state/array before.

From what I have read I need to create a copy of the `modalIngredients` state/array using spread?

And then update all the `name`/`quantity`/`unit` for all the items in the new/copied array I created.

Comment: Can you show how you want the objects in `modalIngreediants` to look after they've been updated? Do you want all the properties from `parsedIngredient` to be added to each modal ingredient object, or just a selected few to be added or used to update existing properties? (eg: you said you wanted `name` updated, but what should this be updated to/with?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I have read I need to create a copy of the `modalIngredients`
> state/array using spread?

No, that's only the case if you're modifying your `modalIngredients` using in-place methods on your array (such as `.slice()`, `arr[index] = newValue`, etc.) which modify the array itself, which you normally want to avoid in React. Since `.map()` returns a new array rather than modifying the existing array, you don't need to copy the original state using the spread syntax.

Instead, what you can do is create copies of the objects inside of your state array by using the spread syntax, and then update and overwrite old properties with their new values (see code comments bellow):

```js
const updatedIngredients = modalIngredients.map((modalIngredient) => {
  const parsedIngredient = parseIngredient(modalIngredient.raw, 'en')
  return { // <--- return a new object...
    ...modalIngredient, // <--- that has all the properties from modalIngredient...
    // v--- with these properties overwritten
    name: parsedIngredient.ingredient,
    unit: parsedIngredient.unit,
    quantity: parsedIngredient.quantity
  };
});
```

Notice that in the above code, nothing is updating your original `modalIngredients` array or the objects within it. The `.map()` produces a new array, and the object literal `{ }` with the spread `...` syntax creates new objects. This is important as in React you should keep your state as readonly and thus avoid directly updating arrays via indexes (`arr[i] =` ) or objects via dot-notation (`obj.foo =`) / bracket notation (`obj['foo'] =` ).

Note: Your original mapping code appears to be written in curly brackets `{` `}`, which suggests you're writing this inside of JSX that you're returning from your component. If that is the case, you'll need to perform this mapping earlier on in your component, as you cannot have an array of objects used directly within your JSX code.

Comment: thank you so much super helpful and your explanation was increble in helping me understand how this works better

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible ways to update the stored values.
But you can solve this problem easily by getting the index of a specific object that you want to update.

For example:

```
const [modalIngredient, setModalIngredient] = useState([
    {
        "raw": "1 (4-5) pound chuck roast",
        "name": null,
        "quantity": 1,
        "unit": ""
    },
    {
        "raw": "salt + pepper",
        "name": null,
        "quantity": 0,
        "unit": ""
    },
    {
        "raw": "2 tablespoons olive oil",
        "name": null,
        "quantity": 2,
        "unit": "tablespoon"
    }
]);
```

Now, write a function to update the values.

```
const updateIngredients = () => {
   setModalIngredients((prevItems) => {
      return prevItems.map((modalIngredient) => {
         if (modalIngredient.raw === "1 (4-5) pound chuck roast") {
            return {
               ...modalIngredient,
               name: "ingredients",
            };
         }
         return modalIngredient;
      });
   });
};
```

This approach creates a new array by mapping over each item in the prevItems array. If the current item matches the criteria, it creates a new object with the same properties as the current item, but with the updated "name" property.

By doing this, we are ensuring that we are working with a new array, which is required for React to recognize the state change and rerender the component accordingly.